# xdotool sleep 1 vs sleep 1, any difference?

Tags: bash, xdotool

Is there any difference between these two sleep commands:

**Either:**

```
xdotool sleep 1
```

**Or:**

```
sleep 1
```

**Example:**

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do

        xdotool mousemove --sync 1000 500
        xdotool click 1

        xdotool sleep 2

        xdotool mousemove --sync 500 250
        xdotool click 1
```

...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script doesn't show the latter, but it would only affect the *bash* script, while `xdotool sleep` is intended to affect the *X display*.  The script could in principle be issuing several requests to `xdotool` in the background, while `xdotool` is responsible for making X events out of those requests.

Further reading:

- [xdotool - command-line X11 automation tool](https://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml)